# Where can I use pre-actions and post-actions for in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I sometimes make new schemes for convenience in Xcode. When I do that there is always an option for pre and post-actions.

Question: What could be an usecase for pre-actions and post-actions?

Answer (score -1):

I do not know much about the subject, but through a quick google search I found 
this excerpt from Chapter 6 of "Xcode Tools Sensei" by Mark Szymczyk:

> Each scheme action has a disclosure triangle next to it in the scheme
>   editor. Clicking the disclosure triangle lets you specify pre-actions
>   and post-actions for a scheme action. Setting up test data is a
>   situation where you would use a pre-action. Uploading an archive to a
>   server is a situation where you would use a post-action.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Did not found that! Do you have any idea what language it it written in? It looks something like linux commandline and C